# VueJS with Vuex - Replace item (object) in array stored in Vuex with splice doesn't re-render list of items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, v-for

I have an array of records.
Each record is an object with **_id (mongo id)**, title, and value (value is an object with amount and currency).

I'm showing the list of records with v-for when ':key' of the list is the id of the record.

It works when I add a record, (using `records.push()` in the store), and delete a record (using `records.splice(idx, 1)`), But when I'm trying to edit a record and change the title or value.amount the list does not re-render and show the list without the change (using records.splice(idx, 1, updatedRecord))

Here My Code:
**Record List**

```html
<template>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
      <ion-label>Title</ion-label>
      <ion-label>Value</ion-label>
      <ion-label />
    </ion-item>
    <RecordPreview
      v-for="record in records"
      :key="record._id"
      :record="record"
      @onEditRecord="onEditRecord"
      @onDeleteRecord="onDeleteRecord"
    />
  </ion-list>
</template>

<script>
import { IonList, IonItem, IonLabel } from '@ionic/vue';
import RecordPreview from './RecordPreview.vue';

export default {
  name: 'RecordList',
  components: {
    RecordPreview,
    IonList,
    IonItem,
    IonLabel,
  },
  props: {
    records: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  emits: ['onEditRecord', 'onDeleteRecord'],
  setup(_, { emit }) {
    function onEditRecord(record) {
      emit('onEditRecord', record);
    }
    function onDeleteRecord(record) {
      emit('onDeleteRecord', record);
    }
    return {
      onEditRecord,
      onDeleteRecord,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**Vuex record module**

```html
import recordService from '../../services/record.service';

export const recordModule = {
  state: () => ({
    records: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    async getRecords({ commit }) {
      const records = await recordService.getRecords();
      commit('setRecords', records);
    },
    async addRecord({ commit }, record) {
      const newRecord = await recordService.addRecord(record);
      commit('addRecord', newRecord);
    },
    async updateRecord({ commit }, record) {
      const res = await recordService.updateRecord(record);
      if (res.modifiedCount > 0) {
        commit('updateRecord', record);
      }
    },
    async removeRecord({ commit }, recordId) {
      const res = await recordService.removeRecord(recordId);
      if (res.deletedCount > 0) {
        commit('removeRecord', recordId);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    setRecords(state, records) {
      state.records = records;
    },
    addRecord(state, record) {
      state.records.push(record);
    },
    updateRecord(state, updatedRecord) {
      const recordIdx = state.records.findIndex((rec) => rec._id === updatedRecord._id);
      state.records.splice(recordIdx, 1, updatedRecord);
    },
    removeRecord(state, recordId) {
      const recordIdx = state.records.findIndex((rec) => rec._id === recordId);
      state.records.splice(recordIdx, 1);
    },
  },
  getters: {
    records(state) {
      return state.records;
    },
  },
};
```

**RecordPreview**

```html
<template>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>
      {{ date }}
    </ion-label>
    <ion-label>
      {{ title }}
    </ion-label>
    <ion-label :color="amount > 0 ? 'success' : 'danger'">
      {{ value }}
    </ion-label>
    <ion-label>
      <ion-button
        color="warning"
        fill="outline"
        @click="onEditRecord"
      >
        Edit
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button
        color="danger"
        fill="outline"
        @click="onDeleteRecord"
      >
        Delete
      </ion-button>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from '@vue/reactivity';
import { IonItem, IonLabel, IonButton } from '@ionic/vue';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

export default {
  name: 'RecordPreview',
  components: {
    IonItem,
    IonLabel,
    IonButton,
  },
  props: {
    record: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
  emits: ['onEditRecord', 'onDeleteRecord'],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const value = computed(() => `${props.record.value.currency} ${props.record.value.amount}`);
    const date = computed(() => dayjs(props.record.date).format('DD-MM-YY'));
    function onEditRecord() {
      emit('onEditRecord', props.record);
    }
    function onDeleteRecord() {
      emit('onDeleteRecord', props.record);
    }
    return {
      amount: props.record.value.amount,
      title: props.record.title,
      date,
      value,
      onEditRecord,
      onDeleteRecord,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**To get the records I'm using getter from the store placed on the parent component of RecordList like that:**

```html
    const records = computed(() => store.getters.records);
```

**package.json**

```html
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.3.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.6",
    "@ionic/vue": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/reactivity": "^3.2.22",
    "@vue/runtime-core": "^3.2.22",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "vue": "^3.2.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.0.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-v5": "npm:fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@^5.0.11",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0",
    "vue-loader-v16": "npm:vue-loader@^16.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

---

P.S.
I tried to create a deep copy of the array and replace all the array. I also tried to create a deep copy of the record, then change and replace it.
And I think the problem is with the key, coz when I tried to change the :key from 'record._id' to 'record 'it re-render the list when I replaced the item (I guess it work because the pointer of the object was changed)

Comment: You must check two cases. First if condition `res.modifiedCount > 0`  is  `true`.  Second check if you have correct `recordIdx`. All your code work correct. Example how it work https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-engelbart-zpu6g

Comment: Also you don't share `RecordPreview` component maybe problem there too

Comment: I checked res.modifiedCount > 0 and it is true, In addition checked the recordIdx and it correct, and the records list are updated in the store (and the getter re called) but don't re-render the recordList component. I guess it on the :key="record._id" (because if I'm changing the _id the list re-rendered), but I'm sure it could work with it, vue v-bind key should work with an id.

Comment: @VitaliyRayets In recordPreview have nothing I just display the fields and have an action buttons that emit the 'updateRecord' with the record to edit.. taht will appear in the edit modal (deep copy of the record from the list)

Comment: Try like this `<RecordPreview v-for="(record, key) in records" :key="key" ...`

Comment: Tried it, and it doesn't work. I also saw in some documentation that it not best practice to use index as a key

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-engelbart-zpu6g all is work correct. I think problem how your render `record` in `RecordPreview` component. Share `RecordPreview`

Comment: Thanks for your help @VitaliyRayets! I'll send the recordsPreview later, but look at this code: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-brook-0p0lb?file=/src/App.vue
 It a bit more like that in my code, with deep copy of the getter to records, and using item from records to update the list. But in the sandbox it update it one time and after that stop the re-rendering, and in my code it doesn't work at all.. (my code is more complicated than it, but not much more complicated)

Comment: @VitaliyRayets I edited the question and added the RecordPreview component code

Comment: Updated Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-rgb-dlw4f?file=/src/App.vue
Here it works. I think my code is the same to this code..
Maybe it's on Ionic? Or Vue version..?

Comment: Share your package.json

Comment: @VitaliyRayets added the package.json to the question.
I tried to change the sandbox vue, vuex etc version like in my package.json, didn't change nothing. Also tried to added ionic and didn't affect

Comment: @VitaliyRayets Thanks for your help! I found the problem in RecordPreview as you said. In return I defined the props value in key of 'title' and 'amount' then the props reactivity has canceled.
Now I changed it to use the props.title and props.value.amount in html and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching records from an API I recommend that you update by fetching from the API, and if you want to update the item within your state, try this:

```
updateRecord(state, updatedRecord) {
  const { title, value } = updatedRecord;
  let recordIdx = state.records.find((rec) => rec._id === updatedRecord._id);

  recordIdx.title = title
  recordIdx.value = value 
  ...
},
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't think it best practice, and search for the right way to update list with objects in VUE.
About using the data from DB, I want to use the local data when it possible (and I believe it possible in this situation), for better performance and show updated data faster.

Comment: Your example incorrect. The `findIndex` method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. `recordIdx` is type `number` and  not object like you think `recordIdx.title = title` . Also `recordIdx` is `const` you can't change it

Comment: @VitaliyRayets Yes, I had not seen it. Thanks